# ReflectiveInjector throws InvalidProviderError

Tags: class, angular, typescript

I am trying to inject 2 services into generic classes using `ReflectiveInjector` as seen in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309481/angular-2-inject-service-into-class)

The first time I call `ReflectiveInjector` on `DebugService` it works completely fine, however if I then replace this with `CourseService`, I recieve the following InvalidProviderError:

> Uncaught InvalidProviderError_nativeError: Error: Invalid provider - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: undefined

---

This is the generic class where I am trying to inject the services.

**Media.ts**

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
import { ReflectiveInjector }                       from '@angular/core';
// other imports
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
import { CourseService , DebugService }             from 'app/services';
//other imports
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


export class Media {
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer;
    private courseService: CourseService;
    private debug: DebugService;

    constructor(_audio: File[], _images: File[], _videos: File[] ) {
        // works fine
        var injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([DebugService]);
        this.debug = injector.get(DebugService);

        // throws InvalidProviderError
        var injector2 = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([CourseService]); 
        this.courseService = injector2.get(CourseService);
    }
```

---

The 2 services are as follows:

**debug.service.ts**

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
import { Injectable }           from '@angular/core';
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
import { environment }          from '../../environments/environment';
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

@Injectable()
export class DebugService {
    constructor() {
        /*stuff*/
    }
}
```

**course-service.service.ts**

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
import { Injectable, EventEmitter, Output }                from '@angular/core';
import { Router }                                          from '@angular/router';
import { Title, DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl}    from '@angular/platform-browser';
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
import { DebugService }                                    from 'app/services';
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


@Injectable()
export class CourseService {

    @Output() preloadData = new EventEmitter<any>();

    // Constructor 1 - called on instantiation of class
    constructor(
        private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
        private router: Router,
        private titleService: Title,
        private debug: DebugService
    ) { /*stuff*/ }
```

---

These services were successfully being used in the `Media` class prior, when I was manually passing `CourseService` and `DebugService` as params to the Media constructor, however wanted to get away from this as it seemed very 'clunky' compared to this more streamlined approach.

i.e.

```
export class Media {
    /*stuff*/
    constructor(_audio: File[], _images: File[], _videos: File[], _courseService: CourseService, _debugService: DebugService ) { /*stuff*/ }
}
```

Media is currently defined within another class's constructor:

```
var preloader = new Preloader(
    new Media(
        // Audio Files
        [
            new File(0, './app/assets/video/Example1.mp3')
        ],
        // Image Files
        [

        ],
        // Video Files
        [
            new File(0, './app/assets/video/Example1.mp4')
        ]
    )
//...
```

Comment: How do you use `Media` class? Have you tried to remove comma character in `Media` constructor?

Comment: @yurzui I have added how I instantiate Media class at the bottom of the question, and I removed that extra comma (whoops) - still does not work however.

Comment: Maybe you have a circular dependency by using app/services barrel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997824/angular-2-di-error-exception-cant-resolve-all-parameters/38000323#38000323

Comment: @yurzui I was literally just reading about this, and  I am going to test the theory asap!

Comment: @yurzui I removed anything that could've caused circular dependency, but this is still erroring in the exact same way.

Comment: Can you create plunker to reproduce it?