# How do you create objects of classes which have dependency injection?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a class like this.

```
export class MyClass {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    //rest of class
}
```

How do I create an object of this class?

Comment: The question cannot gain a quality answer because it lacks the context. Where exactly do you need to create an object and why did you not use DI to do that?

Answer (score 0):

As a normal class, e.g.

```
const object = new MyClass(http); // where http is an injected instance of HttpClient
```

There is no other simple way doing so. You can also go on a dark side and inject the injector, or worse, assigning injector to some global variable / static property and inject whatever you want via injector directly, like e.g. this is done here [Angular 2: Inject service into class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309481/angular-2-inject-service-into-class); however this is not recommended.